# Java Formatter output

Tags: java, formatter

Is it true that the Formatter only writes out when you close the stream?

Code:

```
public void save(String content, String filename) {
    if(filename!=""){
        setFileName(filename);
        try {
            output = new Formatter(new File(fileName));
            output.format("%s",content);
        } catch (FormatterClosedException ex){
            System.err.println("Error writing to file");
            return;
        } catch ( NoSuchElementException ex){
            System.err.println("invalid input");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            output.close();
        }
```

At first I forgot to add the finally block with output.close()  and when the method got called it would not write anything. So is it correct that a formatter only actually writes its content when you close the stream?

Answer (score 5):

The assumption that resource in this case a file is accessed only when you call `close()` **is not valid**.

By calling `close()` you assure that write is done and the resource is released.

The write to it is depend on class `BufferedWriter` this mean that when you exceed the buffer size the data will be moved from it [buffer] to resource [file]. You can force you app to do that by calling `flush()`, and that is what `close()` does.

The default size if buffer is 1KB (8192 bits) long.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):
*The file to use as the destination of this formatter. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.*

Classes whose output is buffered will write their stuff when `flush` is called. This happens implicitely in the `close` method.

You either have to close it or call `flush()`.

Comment: And how does this answer the question? The documentation states no where when a `Formatter` writes to the file.

Comment: *... and is buffered.* Buffering is a concept found in many Java classes, and *always* needs calling `flush` (what also `close` does).

Comment: -1 This is not answer to the question. The aspect that flush() is called by close() is not the case here. The case is that the file will be written when the buffer ends not only on close.

Comment: @Exception1 The question asks if it will only write when calling `flush`, which is not true. Vash`s answer is actually the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

close() implicitly calls flush(), but you can use flush() whenever you need to send data at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `flush()` to write data into stream immediately

Answer (score 0):

The `Formatter` outputs at the underlying buffered stream's discretion, but you can force it to do so by calling `flush()` or `close()`.