# When using the Java Formatter class, why will the constructor create a txt file, but not write to it?

Tags: java, file, format, formatter

This code works, which is odd:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileWork {
    private Formatter r;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            r = new Formatter("c:\\employees.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You got an error");
        }
    }

    public void addRecords(){
        r.format("%d%s%s%n", 34 , " Matt ", "Jenkins");
        r.format("%d%s%s%n", 36 , " John ", "Jackson");
    }
}
```

Then in another class I call the methods.

```
public class FileWork2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileWork g = new FileWork();
        g.openFile(); //creates file
        g.addRecords(); //adds records
    }
}
```

But the following code does not work:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class FileWork3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final Formatter x = new Formatter("c:\\GuestList2.txt");
        x.format("%d", 10);
    }
}
```

This 2nd set of code creates the file GuestList2.txt, but writes nothing to it.  It is blank.  It seems this only works when the Formatter is set as public and private, and called from another class.  I am so confused on the proper way to use the format method.

Comment: Please indent your code with the curly brackets at the top.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#close%28%29

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042609/java-formatter-output

Comment: To make my link a bit clearer: like all the classes dealing with IO, a Formatter must be closed. Do it in a finally block, or with the try-with-resources statement.

Answer (score 1):

It was just because I needed to run the close() method.  Now it works fine, and I have tried it in different ways, with Final, with static methods, and it's writing output fine now.  Thanks for the links and comments.